# jQuery Blur only once clicked off

Tags: jquery, parent-child, parent, children, blur

I have the follow HTML

```
<div id="outerID">
  <input id="inner1" type="text" value="button1"/>
  <input id="inner2" type="text" value="button2"/>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
         <input id="inner3" type="text" value="button2"/>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

With the following jQuery

```
jQuery('#outerID').live('blur', function () {
    alert('fire');
});
```

I only want "blur" to fire when a click is OUTSIDE of `id="outerID"` - a user can click inside as many times as they want inside `id=outerId` but if they 'click off' `id=outerId` then `blur` ?

Comment: It seems to work the way you presented.

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-div-when-click-outside-it - for a more eloquent solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var insideDiv = "";

jQuery('div#outerID').live('click', function (e) {
    if(insideDiv != "" && insideDiv  != 'outerID'){
        alert('fire');
    }
    insideDiv  = "outerID";
    return false;
});

jQuery('div#outerID2').live('click', function (e) {
    if(insideDiv != ""&& insideDiv  != 'outerID2'){
        alert('fire');
    }
    insideDiv  = "outerID2";
    return false;
});
```

I assume outerID2 is the id of the other div.